# PHP Codeigniter delete return true but table not deleted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If i remember correctly, i have tested this function a month ago and its working. Now its not.

This is the model :

```
function delete($table, $id) {
    $query = $this->db->delete($table, array('id'=>$id));
    //return $this->db->affected_rows();
    return $query;
}
```

And i use it on my controller :

```
 $schedule_id = $this->post('id');
   $result = $this->schedule_m->delete('schedule', $schedule_id);
   if($result == true )
        {
            $this->response(array('result' => 'true'), 200);
        }
```

The response is always true, but the row is never deleted.

I tried to return `$this->db->affected_rows();` and use `var_dump`, the result is `int(0)`.

Please kindly help me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `WHERE` condition like

```
function delete($table, $id) {
    $this->db->where('id' , $id);
    $query = $this->db->delete($table);
}
```

And also check whether the table still have the same field `id`.

Comment: Its working now..i dont know what happened @@. I will accept your answer in 9 minutes (SO's system). Thanks a lot